# How to programatically disable/close a DropDownList from the Javascript across all browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I'm not certain which version of Kendo we're using, I've got 2 files:

- `kendo.all.min.js` - Kendo UI v2014.2.903
- `kendo.web.min.js` - Kendo UI v2015.1.429

I have a form with some complex business logic which dictates the Enabled/Disabled state as well as default values for a variety of drop down lists on my webpage. I'm having an issue with one text box which is supposed to disable a dropdown list depending on its value. The controls are defined like so:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeTextboxValue).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "txtSomeField", onfocus = "FocusC0500()", onblur = "BlurC0500(false);FinalizeColor(this);" }))

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeDropdownValue).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "cmbSomeField", onchange = "OnChangeC0600(this, false, false);FinalizeColor(this);"}).BindTo(ViewBag.YesNoDash).OptionLabel(" "))
```

The `BlurC0500` function on the textbox's `onblur` event is the problem. Based on the value entered, the following JS is executed:

```
// the variable cmb refers to cmbSomeField, the dropdown list defined above
if ($("#cmbSomeControl").val() == "" || $("#cmbSomeControl").val() == '0')
{
    cmb.select(0);
    cmb.readonly(true);
    cmb.close();
    SetTabIndexVals("cmbSomeField", "DROPDOWN", -1);
    cmb.wrapper.find('.k-input').css('background', '#DDDDDD');
}
else if (val == "" && $("#cmbSomeControl").val() == '1')
{
    cmb.select(0);
    cmb.readonly(false);
    SetTabIndexVals("cmbSomeField", "DROPDOWN", 1);
    cmb.wrapper.find('.k-input').css('background', '#FFA500');
}
else
{
    cmb.select(1);
    cmb.readonly(true);
    cmb.close();
    SetTabIndexVals("cmbSomeField", "DROPDOWN", -1);
    cmb.wrapper.find('.k-input').css('background', '#DDDDDD');
}
```

Three of us in my office are getting different results depending on the browser used and the specific version of the browser. For example, this works on my machine (Chrome v58) but does not work on my coworker's machine (Chrome v50).

Without `cmb.close();` it seems to work fine in Chrome and FireFox, but not IE -- depending on the version, again.

So how can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

I use the built in enable method to disable and enable kendo dropdownlist instead of setting readonly and close. It worked on multiple browsers(IE, Chrome, Firefox).

```
cmb.enable(true/false);
```